# change div style if I click another div angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i'm getting stuck for change div style when I click another div. I just want to change listAnswer class text-decoration become underline when I click one of ng-repeat div1. I hope someone can help me :( thanks

```
<style>
    .object_screen {
       width: 800px;
       height: 500px;
    }

    .div1 {
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       float: left;
       margin-left: 10px;
    }
</style>

<div class="object_screen">
    <div class="div1" ng-repeat="object in objectList" ng-click="checking(object.name);" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(./img/level/{{ object.image }})}"></div>
</div>
<div class="listAnswer">
    <li ng-repeat="object in objectList">{{ object.name }}</li>
</div>
```

this my angular script

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);
    App.controller('playController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.objectList = [];
        $scope.objectList.push({name:'tony', image:'image1.png'});
        $scope.objectList.push({name:'Jay', image:'image2.png'});
        $scope.objectList.push({name:'Michael', image:'image3.png'});

        $scope.checking= function(nameObject){
            // change text-decoration to underline for class listAnswer
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may declare a variable in your scope to have a Boolean false initially and change it to true in $scope.checking and have the ng-class as in the succeeding line 
div class="listAnswer" ng-class="{ 'your text decoration css class' : watch variable set in the $scope.checking}" your text decoration class will be applied when the variable is set to true

Comment: Praneeth : It sounds good idea but can you give me an example? i'm new using angluarjs. thanks

Comment: this is the test i have performed on my machine <h4 ng-click="downloadFile2()">Click Here</h4>
 
 <h4 ng-class="{ 'css-class' : change }">Here</h4> $scope.change = false;
         
          $scope.downloadFile2 = function(){
           
           $scope.change = true;
           
          }

Comment: thanks for reply, this should be works. but I hope can find antoher solution. cheers! :D